# Why do composition of two unaries become binary operation?

Tags: group-theory, definition

My textbooks introduces a concept of a 'group'.

As an obvious example,  equilateral triangle ABC is used along with all the 6 symmetries it has. Say, I got $f : \{ (A, B); (B, C); (C, A); \}$. It is **unary** since depends upon exactly 1 argument. Then the composition $f \circ f$ considered: $f \circ f : \{ (A, f[f(A)]); (B, f([f(B)]); (C, f([f(C)]); \}$, **which is still unary**, for exmaple: $(f \circ f) (A) = f (f (A)) = f(B) = C$. And then my textbooks jumps outright to the group's definition, saying that there should exist a **binary operation** and whatnot more.

As far as I understand, a **binary operation** is such $f(x, y)$ that $y$ **can not** be computed even though one knows $x$'s value. So both variables are independent, like $T \land F$ from the Boolean algebra. This requirement does not hold for the case above.

So, could you help me out with a confusion I described? Maybe it makes sense to consider some other groups like $<\mathbb{Z}, +>$ for clarification?

Comment: It seems to me that "composition" is the step that introduces the binary operation. Your binary operation is on maps (like $f$), not on points (like $A$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments on the other answer, it might be less confusing to consider the group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$. Here the elements of the group are numbers, and addition is clearly a binary operation: you need to add two numbers $x+y$.

In the case of triangle symmetries, the elements of the group are themselves unary operations on the vertices, and composition is a binary operation on unary operations. Much more confusing.

Comment: So the whole idea that mentioned God-blessed binary operation should be a mapping $(G, G) \mapsto G$? But for triangles that is not true: you defined a binary operation as a way to combine **mappings** $G \mapsto G$ rather than elements of $G$. Does it make any change?

Comment: @SerejaBobolubov Look carefully back at your textbook. In the triangle case, the group $G$ is the group of _symmetries_, not the group of vertices. I.e., $G = \{f,g,\dots\}$, not $G = \{A,B,C\}$.

Comment: @SerejaBobolubov Also, a note on being careful with terminology: a binary operation is a _map_ $(G,G) \to G$, but it's not a _bijection_.

Comment: Now I got it. Indeed, I misunderstood what **symmetry** is. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I think (based especially on your comments to RGS's answer) you're having a bit of a type confusion *(EDIT: not really, see comment below)*:

A group is a pair $(A, *)$ where $A$ is a set - of any type whatsoever - and $*$ is a binary operation on $A$ (*satisfying certain properties*). One perfectly normal example is:

> $A$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ and $*$ is $+$. It's easy to check that the group axioms hold: e.g. $a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c$.

However, the following is *also* a great example:

> $A$ is the set of bijective functions from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ and $*$ is composition. *(This is similar in spirit to the example you're asking about; I think while this one is a bit more abstract, thinking about it will help build intuition.)* Here, **even though elements of $A$ are functions**, as far as the group is concerned they're just "things." And composition takes two "things" and spits out a third "thing," so in principle this could be a group (and indeed it is).

I think your confusion is that you're expecting elements of the group to always "not look like functions." Part of what makes group theory so powerful, though, is that they *can*. For example, [Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory) (which was the original motivation for group theory!) shows how we can prove things about fields by looking at groups of functions from fields to fields.

Comment: Thanks so much for detailed answer. I have no problems with functions as an elements of the certain set. The only mistake I did is that I thought about the symmetry as an ordered sequence of vertices rather than a bijectives maps.

Comment: @SerejaBobolubov Ah. Well, in that case I missed the mark, but I'll leave the answer up since I think others may find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The unaries you are talking about are symmetries: they send a vertex to another vertex. In your example, $f$ sends the vertex $A$ to vertex $B$.

The binary operation your textbook must be talking about (I am only guessing, but I think this is a good guess) is a binary operation that takes two symmetries and returns another symmetry. In your case, the binary operation is function composition. You took the pair $(f, f)$ and then applied function composition to it, yielding a new symmetry $g$ of which you calculated $g(A) = C$.

Comment: Sure, but the composition that you mentioned still requires ONLY SINGLE argument, namely $A$. It is sufficient to compute $g(A) = C$. Then $g$ is unary rather than binary.

Comment: $g$ is unary but the operation $\circ$ is a binary function, receiving TWO symmetries and returning one.

Comment: @SerejaBobolubov The binary operation is not $g$ -- that one is unary, like you said. The binary operation is the composition -- instead of writing $f \circ f$, let's write $C(f,f)$. We have $C(f,f) = g$. $C$ is binary because we could also consider $C(f,g)$, and that would give us another symmetry.

Comment: @Y.Forman all right, seems pretty clear. Than why $<\mathbb{Z}, +>$ forms a group as well? I see no way how $f(x, y) = x + y$ could became $C(f, f)$ from your example. Is there a gap or I am just blinded to a obvious things?

Comment: @SerejaBobolubov In $(\mathbb{Z},+)$, the elements of the group are the integers, not the functions. The operation is $C(x,y) = x+y$. It seems very different from composition of symmetries of the triangle, but that's the power of group theory: it highlights the similarities between the two cases.